# SONAR 6500 series

Tags: microcontroller, sonarqube

I have to program a 6500 series SONAR connected to an arduino micro controller to do the scanning of a room to detect any movement. The codes need to be in C++. Any idea of the codes to be used? I am new to all this and I am really stuck.

Comment: It looks like you have misunderstood the "sonarqube" tag. It is for discussion of a particular source code analysis tool named SonarQube, not discussion of sensors using SONAR (SOund Navigation And Ranging) to detect movement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SonarSource commercial plugin that analyzes C/C++ http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/

SonarSource website also lists an external C++ plugin http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/External+Plugins. Now you won't get support from the SonarSource team on this plugin.

If you are "new to all this", I suggest you define precisely your objectives, according to your project strategy: do you just want to analyze your code from time to time or do you want to put in place a whole process as Continuous Integration (CMS, build, testing, SCA, ...).

Do not hesitate to ask for further precisions.
Regards.

Comment: I want to know the C++ codes to be used so as to make my 6500 series sonar scan a room and alert me of an intrusion. Thanking you for your kind consideration.